# HTML5: Edition for Web Authors

Tags: html

I am stressed out because of lack of clarification and further guidance on the matter from W3. On this link:  [HTML5: Edition for Web Authors](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-html5-author-20130528/)

They state:

> This document has been discontinued and is only made available for historical purposes. The [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/) specification includes a style switcher that will hide implementer-oriented content.

Why is this so? Where can I find the newest edition? Is there even a new edition of this, or am I forced to use edition with user-agent (UA) implementation details?

Answer (score 1):

Click the link in the quote to view the [HTML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/).  Then, click the button in the top right to turn on developer styles:

[image: html 5 spec with style switcher button]

That is the "style switcher" referred to in the quote.

Comment: So I can safely use this version  [link](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/Overview.html) and just hide UA content?

Comment: Hooray! A spec that isn't 10 years old. Those are rare now, as w3c is lazy.